# Can we rewrite lookbehind in terms of the if-then-else?

Tags: regex

Given two regexs `expr1` and `expr1`, can we write a lookbehind `(?<=expr1)expr2` equivalently in terms of the if-then-else construct?

For example, is the lookbehind `(?<=expr1)expr2` equivalent to `(expr1)(?(-1)expr2|expr3)`, where `expr3` is some regex which is never possible to match?

In other words,  are the two regex's `(?<=expr1)expr2` and`(expr1)(?(-1)expr2|expr3)` describe the same?

If yes, how do you choose `expr3`, so that it is never possible to match?

Thanks?

Comment: @Dalorzo: `(?(-1)...|...)` is a conditional that tests if the last defined capturing group exists.

Comment: What book? btw, I gave you the link. @Dalorzo

Comment: @Tim See update for the other part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do the two regex's (?<=expr1)expr2 and (expr1)(?(-1)expr2|expr3)
>   describe the same?

**No. They match different strings.**

`(?<=expr1)expr2` can only ever match one thing: `expr2`, and not just anywhere: the `expr2` in `expr1expr2`.

In contrast, `(expr1)(?(-1)expr2|expr3)` can only ever match: `expr1expr2`.

Clearly, `expr2` and `expr1expr2` are different strings. The answer is no.

**..but the other answer is Yes:**

`Can we write a lookbehind (?<=expr1)expr2 equivalently in terms of the if-then-else construct?`

Yes. This uses in an-then-else (the else is implied): `(?(?<=expr1)expr2)`, and it too matches `expr1expr2`. Of course, it too uses a lookbehind.

The "implied else" doesn't sound right to you? Add a `|`, as in `(?(?<=expr1|)expr2)`

**What about expr3?**

Your last regex `(expr1)(?(-1)expr2|expr3)` will never be able to match `expr3`. If you want it to have a chance, you would have to make the capture group optional: `(expr1)?(?(-1)expr2|expr3)`